# How to I pass additional data to a bound datagrid?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, datagrid

So say I have a data grid bound to a object, it there any way to pass an addition list/variable to it?

specifically:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="IndoorUnitTable" ItemsSource="{Binding BoundList, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"   
...
       <DataTemplate x:Name="PropertyFromOtherTable">
             <TextBlock Text="{Binding OtherListIWant, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource ConverterForTwoLists}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
       </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Your questions is very unclear.  Do you want to combine the lists so that the number of rows in the table will be the sum of rows in each list?  Or do you want to join the lists such that the number of columns in the table is the sum of columns in the two lists?  A different approach is required for each.

Comment: Your question is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the ConverterParameter in your Binding, this will be passed to the converter as parameter. I hope that I have understood your question correctly ;)